# How am I able to make a gradient which pops up if you are hovering over a button but the button havt have still the same backgroundimage

Tags: css

I would like to have a button in css, that have a background image and if you hover over it you get a gradient. (see picture)

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

One way would be to use a `button` with a background image and attach a pseudo element to the button that has opacity when the button is hovered.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}

button::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(125,126,125,0.5) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,0.5) 100%);
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

button:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x300)" alt=""></button>
```